# How to read Operational Amplifier documentation

Tags: amplifier, operational-amplifier

I am reading the documentation of an operational amplifier, and I do not understand certain values. For example, for this AO http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6601.pdf :

- The documentation indiactes the bandwidth is 250, does this refers as the difference between the high and low cutoff frequencies, or the average value of the cutoff frequencies? (cf fc here : 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency)
- About the figures page 12, the curve start to decrease at approximately 100 MHz, the name of this values is the high cutoff frequency, what is the name of this value in the document?
- Why are there different curves? I see that the gain (Av in the document) is the parameters that changes between all the curves, but I thought that the gain was measured, not a parameter. Plus, it is negative for some curves.

I know this is very basic questions, but I do not know where to find answers because I do not know the abbreviations. Thnk you for your time.

Comment: In your case, I always recommend reading "Opamps for everyone", it's a free download at: https://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf

Comment: Each one of your questions is relevant but, given you ask three with a high possibility of follow up questions (and there could easily be hundreds if you are intent on understanding op-amps) and your knowledge is low I have to vote to close the question.

Comment: What is an "AO"?

Comment: Become capable of sketching the BODE (gain + phase) response of your opamp in logFreg/logGain axis to examine gain accuracy (1/1+GH) at higher frequencies, to examine Zout and thus propensity to oscillate;

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully, that 250 MHz BW is when Av = +1 meaning the opamp is used with feedback and the circuit has a gain of 1, it buffers the signal. It is the frequency at which that gain of 1 ( 0 dB) has dropped 3 dB so the gain at 250 MHz will be - 3 dB.

This is an absolute value, not a difference. In practice the average of many opamps will be more than 250 MHz so that the manufacturer can **guarantee** that the value is almost always at least 250 MHz.

But as a designer I would not use this opamp if I **must have** that 250 MHz in my application, I'd use a faster opamp to get some margin and possibly change the feedback around the opamp such that I get a **predictable** bandwidth of 250 MHz (or whatever I want).

That the curve starts to drop around 100 MHz is meaningless, what is important is **how much** drop it has at a certain frequency. Almost everyone uses the -3 dB point as the interesting point. -3 dB because when the signal is fed to a resistor, at -3 dB the **power will be halved**.

Also note here the value of Av = 2. Since at Av = 1 and Gain times BW remains constant, the expected BW will be 125 MHz. Note (first graph) that the amplitude of the signal matters, at higher amplitudes the BW will be lower. Also the supply voltage matters and also other parameters. That is what these plots show.

A negative gain simply means that the opamp is used in an **inverting** configuration. The signal is inverted or "upside down". For a single frequency signal you could also say it is 180 degrees shifted in phase.

I'll say it again: read [Opamps for everyone](https://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf) !

It is **the** proper introduction to everything related to opamps.

Comment: whoa! 464 pages. You sure get your money's'worth with that download.

Comment: Since it's free (gratis) the page/$ is infinite ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Always** look at the open-loop gain plot of the amplifier, as there is no creative marketing there. For the LMH6601 the small-signal open-loop gain is the following,
[image]

For a typical op-amp with good phase margin (i.e. crosses 0dB at 20 dB/dec, 60+ deg phase margin). You can graphically solve the closed loop non-inverting response by simply plotting \$ 1/\beta\$ where beta is the feedback factor.

A sample schematic on a non-inverting amplifier is shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkYYs4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here beta equals,
$$ \beta = \dfrac{ R_g}{ R_g + R_f } $$

Equivalently the inverse of the feedback factor beta is,

$$ 1/\beta =  \dfrac{ R_g + R_f}{ R_g } = 1 + \dfrac{ R_f }{ R_g } $$

---

The reason the amplifier you've listed makes a 250 MHz claim is that in the +1 Av case the amplifier has extremely poor phase margin and forms a complex pole-pair. So it does provide a -3dB point of 250 MHz. However, it also has an ringing step-response and a multi-dB boost in gain before the -3dB point.